# How to resize / while running system off of it

Tags: debian, partition, windows, root-filesystem

all! I'm running Debian 10.5 and looking to dual-boot Windows 10. I only have one hard drive. I also have no spare CDs/DVDs or USB drives around. I want to follow [these](https://superuser.com/questions/457640/how-can-i-install-windows-7-without-dvd-or-usb-on-linux) instructions, but I only have one partition on my HDD. My question is, how can I use something like gparted (though any editor will work) to resize /dev/sda1 while my system is running on it? I also have GRUB 2, though I doubt that has anything helpful. I want to make free space on the *right*, so it won't affect my existing Debian install.
[image: GParted window]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. This usage is specifically disallowed. The disk metadata exists in too many separate places (on disk, in kernel data structures, in `gparted`). Keeping them all synchronized is too hard for software to do. Boot from a Live USB.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having. I don't have any USB, CD, SD card, etc laying around. I need some way to edit partitions on sda while running off of it.

Comment: Did you not read my answer? "This usage is specifically disallowed". Simply repeating your requirements is like the "I want a pony" loop.